# Dynamic XYBarChart with DefaultIntervalXYDataset()

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm trying to combine a `XYBarChart` as well as a normal `XYPlot` in a `CombinedDomainXYPlot`. The domain axis is a `DateAxis()`, allowing me to plot time series.

For the `XYPlots`, I can add datapoints dynamically using:

```
[XYSeries].add(time, value);
```

However, for the `XYBarChart`, I'm using JFreeChart's [`DefaultIntervalXYDataSet`](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/xy/DefaultIntervalXYDataset.html). For this class, the method for adding a data-series, is as follows:

> `addSeries(java.lang.Comparable seriesKey, double[][] data)`
>
> Adds a series or if a series with the same key already exists replaces the data for that series, then sends a DatasetChangeEvent to all registered listeners.

Clearly, the parameter `double[][] data` does not allow for *dynamic* changes to the data, in the sense that I can't simply add the new datapoints to the series itself. Is there a way to add datapoints to the `XYBarChart` dynamically? Or do I have to replace the complete `double[][]` in every update?

Ultimately, my goal is to add bars dynamically *and* give these bars a dynamic color.

Comment: Can you share code that you already have, if any?

Comment: @FreekdeBruijn I had code but it didn't work so I deleted it. The barchart demo of jFreeChart is almost identical to my situation so perhaps we can try to make that one dynamic.

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11469865/making-dynamic-line-chart-using-jfree-chart-in-java, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17528820/dynamic-chart-using-jfreechart, or http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Chart/JFreeChartDynamicDataDemo.htm? These pages appear to be promising at first glance.

Comment: Use `addSeries()` to replace the previous series with a new one, or extend `AbstractIntervalXYDataset` to allow updating in place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an instance of `org.jfree.data.xy.XYIntervalSeriesCollection`. This dataset implements the `IntervalXYDataset` interface and allows the dynamic addition of further data items.
The relationship between the `DefaultIntervalXYDataSet` and `XYIntervalSeriesCollection` is similar to that between `DefaultXYDataset` and `XYSeriesCollection`.